# Invoke .NET method via COM, with a ref array

Tags: c#, c++, com

I have a .NET DLL that exposes a method that looks like this in C#:

`void TestMethod(ref TestClass[] parameter)`

Where TestClass is a regular C# class that has a COM-visible interface, and I'm supposed to call the method with an array with one element. ​I can't figure out how to invoke this via COM from a C++ program.

That parameter becomes a SAFEARRAY**. Currently, I'm doing this, where m_Object is a smart pointer to the class that has TestMethod:

```
VARIANT* current = NULL;
HRESULT hrx = SafeArrayAccessData(ret, (LPVOID*)&current);
ITestClassPtr item;
item.CreateInstance(__uuidof(TestClass));
current->vt = VT_UNKNOWN;
current->punkVal = item.GetInterfacePtr();
SafeArrayUnaccessData(ret);
HRESULT hr = (*m_Object)->TestMethod(&ret);
```

​This results in 0x80131533 "A mismatch has occurred between the runtime type of the array and the sub type recorded in the metadata".

I have also tried:

```
ITestClassPtr item;
item.CreateInstance(__uuidof(TestClass));
long i = 0;
SafeArrayPutElement(ret, &i, item);
HRESULT hr = (*m_Object)->TestMethod(&ret);
```

Which results in an unhelpful 0x80131600.

I've also tried using a CComSafeArray, but I'm getting the same results (it's just a wrapper around SAFEARRAY anyway).

I do not have sources for the DLL, and I can't debug into it. I've searched around the web, and I can find lots of examples for how to invoke a C# DLL via COM, but none that covers specifically how to pass ref arrays of classes from C++ to C#.

Any ideas?

Comment: The first snippet would only be appropriate if the argument is object[].  Nothing wrong with the second snippet.  0x80131600 tells you that the C# code threw an ApplicationException.  That is a lousy practice, goes back to the .NET 1.x days.  Tells you that it is unlikely that anybody will answer the phone call you need to make to get the help you need.  You'd definitely consider investing in a good disassembler.

Comment: @HansPassant that sounds like I may be doing everything right with the second approach, at least with regards to COM object passing. Thanks, that's useful.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have these C# classes:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
public class TestClass1
{
    public void SayHello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello 1");
    }

    public void TestMethod(ref TestClass2[] parameter)
    {
        parameter[0].SayHello();
    }
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
public class TestClass2
{
    public void SayHello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello 2");
    }
}
```

You can register it and create the type library with a command line like this:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe ClassLibrary1.dll /codebase /tlb
```

If you look at the typelib created using [OleView from Windows SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/ole-com-object-viewer), `TestMethod` is declared like this:

```
[id(0x60020005)]
HRESULT TestMethod([in, out] SAFEARRAY(_TestClass2*)* parameter);
```

So its a `SAFEARRAY` of `_TestClass2` pointers (`IUnknown`-derived), and you can create it and use it like this (assuming Visual Studio support):

```
...
#import "c:\mypath\ClassLibrary1.tlb" raw_interfaces_only

using namespace ClassLibrary1;


int main()
{
  CoInitialize(NULL);
  {
    // warning: all error checks omitted

    CComPtr<_TestClass1> tc1;
    tc1.CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(TestClass1));
    tc1.SayHello(); // outputs "Hello 1"

    CComPtr<_TestClass2> tc2;
    tc2.CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(TestClass2));

    SAFEARRAY* psa = SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_UNKNOWN, 0, 1);

    LONG index = 0;
    // note this will call AddRef on tc2 so it's safe
    SafeArrayPutElement(psa, &index, (_TestClass2*)tc2);

    tc1->TestMethod(&psa); // Outputs "Hello 2"

    SafeArrayDestroy(psa);
  }

  CoUninitialize();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. At this point, I think my problem must be inside the DLL, rather than with COM...